# NSUserdefaults doesn't call functions

Tags: call, nsuserdefaults

I'm using NSUserdefaults to save/load values (slider, switch, label) but it does work only on the ViewController layer and doesn't have effect on the functions that graphic elements call.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What operating system are you talking about?  Please add O/S and language tags.

Comment: OSX El Capitan 10.11.5, XCode 8 beta, Objective C (libpd: pure data for IOS library).

Thanks a lot for your answer.